# Disabled "Ambient mode" keeps resetting on Youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I keep disabling "Ambient Mode", but it keeps getting enabled. I'm not sure whether it's because I'm using multiple computers or whether the cookie is just resetting or something. Is there a way to permanently disable it? Not excluding use of an extension.

[image]

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/12827017?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop -> Quoting: *Once you turn on Dark theme, ambient mode is automatically enabled.*